# SP2013 and Report Viewer Control

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, sharepoint-2013, claims-based-identity

I have a SharePoint 2013 server with Claims Based Authentication and I would like to display SSRS (SQL 2012) reports using Report Viewer Control (11.0.0.0). When I try to run the report I get following error:

> The user does not exist or is not unique.

The same code works completly perfect on SP2010 servers. I've found out that when I pass user credentials to the report viewer control:

```
IReportServerCredentials irsc = new CustomReportCredentials("userName", "password", "domain");
ReportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = irsc;
```

the report runs without any error. I'm pretty sure that the issue is somehow connected with Claims Based Authentication.

Is it possible to make reports running without passing credentials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i remember correctly, SSRS doesn't support claims based auth, but it should use the ClaimsToWindowsTokenService to convert them into windows credentials. Can you check if this service is running, and if it has enough permissions (and it needs quite a few).

Have a look on this [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231678) article